# colab crashed due to unknown reasons

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Hi I am working in google colab and it crashing with unknown reason,
I've tried to view runtime logs and I am getting this error
ERROR:asyncio:Future exception was never retrieved

Can someone please hep me with this issue

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thankyou for replying google colab is crashing for unknown reasons is the issue, I have tried switching devices but it doesnt work